# HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name is lost

Tags: asp.net, iis, authentication, forms-authentication

I'm using ASP.NET forms authentication in my web application.recently i found a strange behavior. everything was working fine in production environment.with .net 4.0 and IIS 7.in the login user enter username and password and logged in then suddenly `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` is lost.this does not happen every time only in some occasions.i have unable to reproduce the issue in my development environment.i have checked `if(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)` it's also true authentication ticket user data is not empty also.only `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` is empty.plz help

code in Login button

```
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            dtUserDetails = new DataTable();
            if (UserRepositoryBL.ValidateUser(txtUserName.Text.Trim(), Password.Text.Trim(), out dtUserDetails))
            {

                AuthUser au = new AuthUser();
                if (dtUserDetails.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    DataRow DR = dtUserDetails.Rows[0];
                    au.UserID = Convert.ToInt32(DR["UserID"].ToString());
                    au.UserNo = DR["UserNo"].ToString();
                    au.UserName = DR["UserName"].ToString();
                    au.Password = DR["Password"].ToString();
                }
                string userData = au.ToString();

                FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(

             2,                             // Version number

             txtUserName.Text.Trim(),      // Username

             DateTime.Now,                  // Issue date

             DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60), // Expiration date

             false,                         // Persistent?

             userData                 // User data

         );



                string eticket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

                if (Request.Cookies[txtUserName.Text] != null)
                {
                    //HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie(txtUserName.Text);
                    //myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
                    Request.Cookies[txtUserName.Text].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
                    Request.Cookies.Remove(txtUserName.Text);
                }

                HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("SiteCookie", eticket);
               // HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("SiteCookie", eticket);
                cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60);

                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtUserName.Text, false);
               // cookie.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath;
                FormsAuthentication.RenewTicketIfOld(ticket); 

                Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);



                BasePage.ActivityLog("User Login", txtUserName.Text.Trim(), true, Request.RawUrl);
                string url = FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(txtUserName.Text, false);

                Response.Redirect(url);

                //  FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(LoginUser.UserName, false);

            }
            else
            {
                FailureText.Text = "Your login attempt was not successful. Please try again.";
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="60" cookieless="UseCookies" defaultUrl="~/Landing.aspx" protection="All"/>
        </authentication>

        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />

        </authorization>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your session time is limited to 60 minutes. Does the problem only occur for people with an expired session? Might explain why you can't reproduce this on your development machine because you simply don't wait that long?